# Spark application hangs while filtering null rows

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a spark application which is written in java and one of the feature that I'm trying to add is filtering null rows (rows where all (or most) of the columns are null)

In my dataframe, apart from an obvious non-null monotonically increasing id for each record that gets generated while loading the file in the dataframe, most of the concerned columns are null hence I wanted to filter such rows.

```
df = df.filter("column_A is not NULL OR column_B is not NULL OR column_C is not NULL ... upto 15-20 columns");

--this way I'll have the dataframe where at-least one of the concerned columns is not null. And as soon as it encounter a non-null value for a column then it will not look for the further values in different columns
```

My configuration:

driver-memory : 1GB, executor memory : 10GB, no-of-executors : 1, no of cores : 4

---

it works fine for a dataframe of 870k records when I consider 5 columns for nullability check. It works under 4-5 minutes. But it fails for 600k records when I consider 30 columns for nullability check. The entire application hangs where I can't see the executors' status and after 30-40 minutes I have to kill the application.

I've tried giving 15GB and 20GB memory to the executor while keeping all the values same but in vain. I'm using spark-core_2.11 2.4.8 version.

Comment: if you group some of those checks into different fields e.g. 5 fields of 6 or's each then filter on the 5 fields all being true does it complete more quickly / at all?  It's possible you are hitting catalyst compilation limits on the very large or (method size / cache alignment etc.).  It's one of the things I had to work around with [Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/). 
Also please add which spark version you are using to the question.  Some versions, later 3.x for example, won't complain with 64k generated function size limits but can run more slowly, earlier versions throw.

Comment: @Chris Added the spark version at the end. What do you mean by grouping the fields? As in you want me to create 4-5 new fields(columns) by concatenating 5 columns each and then check for nullability in those newly created 5 columns?

Comment: mostly, not nullability of those 5 columns, just if they are true or not nullscol1 and nulllscol2 and .... where nullscol1 is "column_A is not null and columnB ... and column_F is not null" etc.